# Can poly plastic water storage tank be used to store hot water?

Tags: water, plastic, temperature, polyurethane, water-tank

Another set of questions in context of my home-brew solar water heater:

1. Can poly-plastic water storage tanks, be used to store hot water (140deg F / 60deg C) ?
2. How can I thermally insulate a 50 gallon / ~190 litre, vertical poly plastic water tank (like the ones shown [here](http://www.tank-depot.com/productdetails.aspx?part=A-VT0020-16)), to minimize heat-loss overnight ?

Comment: I have seen commercially made solar hot water tanks made of poly but don't know the composition to avoid leaching

Comment: Thanks @UNECS. Good to know that there are commercially made solar hot water tanks made from poly. Regular water storage tanks, I believe - are anyhow expected to withstand water temperatures of upto 50degC, but reading around a bit, I think typical solar heated water can easily reach 75-80degC (peak), which is really pushing the limits.